# How do I trim the number of words in Python?

Tags: python, string

For example...

```
s = 'The fox jumped over a big brown log.'

k = FUNCTION(s,4)

k should be... "The fox jumped over"
```

I can write my own function that splits on whitespace, cuts the list and then joins the list. But that is too much work.

Anyone else knows a simpler way?

Comment: In my opinion, that _is_ the simpler way. Whether it's sufficiently efficient isn't for me to say, but remember: code first, optimize later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def f(s, n):
    return ' '.join(s.split()[:n])
```

But it is still splitting, slicing and joining...

Comment: Your function returns ['The', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over'] not "The fox jumped over".  You need to return " ".join( s.split()[:n] ) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = "Hello how are you?"
' '.join(x.split()[1:3])
>>> "how are"
```

you can then change the numbers 1 and 3 in the list to get which words you want it to return

```
def split_me(string, start, end, skip):
    return ' '.join(string.split()[start:end:skip])
```

remember lists are indexed starting at 0 and the skip is so you can skip words:

```
split_me("Hello how are you", 0, 3, 2)
>>> 'hello are'
```

Comment: Pointless `start` and `skip` arguments. Following this style you could add such arguments as `split_string`, `join_string`, etc. The problem is solved, stop coding and move on :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say "that is too much work"? Too much work for you, or too much for the computer? Is that code part of some performance critical code?

Just do what works and move on to something more important.

Comment: @alex: Learning how to do things *efficiently* is important. However, this should come after **learning how to do things**. And nowhere does "short" come into it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
def f(s, n):
    return " ".join( s.split()[:n] )
```